# class getter rand variable

Tags: c++, variables, random

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Passenger {
private:
        int ticket ;
        int half ;
    public:
        Passenger(int ticket=rand() % 2, int half=rand() % 2) {                 //  Construct passenger
                cout << "passenger was constructed with " << ticket << " ticket and " << half << " half ticket" <<endl;
        }
        ~Passenger() {
                cout << "passenger was destructed" <<endl;
        }

        int getTicket()const{
            cout << ticket <<endl;
            return ticket;
        };

        int getHalf()const{
            return half;
        };
};


int main(){
    Passenger m;
    m.getTicket();  
}
```

`getTicket` always prints 64 instead of the 0 or 1 that prints when the constructor is called.

I couldn't fix it with this and I don't know that many things for rand()

Comment: Another issue in your code aside from your actual problem, don't use `using namespace std` in a header. The STL is big, and therefore, this can easily lead to collisions. If you don't write out the namespace later on, rather go with `using std::cout;` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are providing default values for the parameters of the constructor `Passenger`, but you are not initializing your class attributes ticket and half.

You may have initialized those parameters in `Passenger::Passenger` with a default value, but unless you assign those parameters to your function members, the attributes `Passenger::ticket` and `Passenger::half` will not be initialized with the values you seemingly want to assign to them.

In essence, you should update your constructor as follows:

```
Passenger::Passenger(int ticket=rand() % 2, int half=rand() % 2) {
    //  Construct passenger
    cout << "passenger was constructed with " << ticket << " ticket and " << half << " half ticket" <<endl;
    this->ticket = ticket;
    this->half = half;
}
```

You can also use an initialization list as given below.

```
class Passenger {
    Passenger(int ticket=rand() % 2, int half=rand() % 2) : ticket(ticket), half(half) {}
    ...  // Rest of the class definition
};
```

Comment: Passenger(int t, int h):ticket(t)=rand() % 2, half(h)=rand() % 2)
would this be right as initialization?

Comment: Using an initialization list is another way to go, yeah.

Comment: To add to this, I'd recommend to John John to read into the term Variable Shadowing. While the answer is perfectly right, it might be that John is not familiar with this concept and will assume that `this.` is needed in any case, not just when he overshadows his members with arguments.